# How to implement TextWatcher for SearchDialog

Tags: android

I need to update my `ListView` according to the userinput in `SearchDialog`. For this I need to set a `TextWatcher`  for `SearchDialog`. How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it as below:

```
yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // process new items for list view

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // push new items into adapter and call notifyDataSetChanged() on it

    }
});
```

Comment: I know about that. What I'm asking is how can I implement this for a SearchDialog(quicksearchbox)

Comment: without showing your code, it would be hard to guess an answer

Comment: I want something similar to SearchView.OnQueryTextListener for QSB. I can't use SearchView.OnQueryTextListener because it only supports API 11+. Hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did actually a few months ago to achieve the same thing that you need. I had to sort my list view depending on user input while I was populating the list view from sqlite database with sqlite statements. Not sure if it's the best way,but in my situation it works perfectly.

So on my `EditText` field I add this (which name is `searchBar`) :

```
searchString = "";
    searchBar.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // this is where actually I was changing the sqlite statement which sort my list view
            names.clear();
            categories.clear();
            paths.clear();
            count.clear();
            cardId.clear();
            myCardID.clear();


            searchString = s.toString();
            Log.e("","searchString : "+searchString);
            sqlQuery = getSqlStatement(sort, collId, ascDesc,searchString);
            Log.e(""," sqlquery : "+sqlQuery);
            sqlQuery = getSqlStatement(sort, collId, ascDesc, searchString);
            Cursor cursor = userDbHelper.executeSQLQuery(sqlQuery);
            if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
                noCards.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                noCards.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    for (cursor.move(0); cursor.moveToNext(); cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                        objectId = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("objectId")));
                        cardId.add(objectId);

                        title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("title"));
                        catTitle = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("catTitle"));
                        if(extra!=0 && sort!=3){
                            tags.setText(catTitle);
                        }
                        int repeats = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("repeatsCount")));
                        count.add(repeats);

                                    String cardsm = "SELECT objectId FROM cardmedias " +
                                                    "WHERE cardId="+ 
                                                    objectId + 
                                                    " AND mediaType=" + 
                                                    5012;

                                    Cursor cardsM = userDbHelper.executeSQLQuery(cardsm);
                                    if (cardsM.getCount() == 0) {
                                        String defCard = "SELECT objectId FROM collectionmedias " +
                                                         "WHERE collectionId="+ 
                                                         collId + 
                                                         " AND mediaType=" + 
                                                         3003;

                                        Cursor getDefCard = userDbHelper.executeSQLQuery(defCard);

                                        getDefCard.moveToFirst();

                                        objectID = Integer.parseInt(getDefCard.getString(getDefCard
                                                .getColumnIndex("objectId")));

                                        String filename = "mediacollection-"+objectID;
                                        if(storageID==1){
                                            path = RPCCommunicator.getImagePathFromInternalStorage(servername, userId, filename, getApplicationContext());
                                        } else if(storageID==2){
                                            path = RPCCommunicator.getImagePathFromExternalStorage(servername, userId, filename);
                                        }
                                        hm.put(objectID, path);

                                        path = hm.get(objectID);
                                        paths.add(path);
                                        names.add(title);
                                        categories.add(catTitle);
                                    } else if (cardsM.getCount() > 0) {
                                        for (cardsM.move(0); cardsM.moveToNext(); cardsM.isAfterLast()) {
                                            objectID = Integer.parseInt(cardsM.getString(cardsM
                                                    .getColumnIndex("objectId")));

                                            String filename = "mediacard-"+objectID;
                                            if(storageID==1){
                                                path = RPCCommunicator.getImagePathFromInternalStorage(servername, userId, filename, getApplicationContext());
                                            } else if(storageID==2){
                                                path = RPCCommunicator.getImagePathFromExternalStorage(servername, userId, filename);
                                            }
                                            hm.put(objectID, path);

                                            path = hm.get(objectID);
                                            paths.add(path);
                                            names.add(title);
                                            categories.add(catTitle);
                                        }
                                    }
                                    cardsM.close();
                    }
            }
            cursor.close();
                    // don't forget to add this!!!
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        }
    });
```

And in my `onCreate()`  actually I'm doing the same thing as in `TextWatcher` to sort my list view, so I think you can implement the same logic as I did.

If you have any problems to do that, just paste some of your code so we can help you! : )

Hope this helps!